# Set cookie with option js

Tags: javascript, c#, cookies, blazor-server-side

Is it possible to set cookie with option in js, for example in c# i have CookieOptions

```
var options = new CookieOptions
{
    IsEssential = true
};
```

I know that in js i can set cookie like that:  `document.cookie = cookieString`
But how to set with options?

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

I don't know that does there has any other js methods can use like C#'s options.

this two js functions I wrote before
`setCookie` and `getCookieValue` that can use to set cookie

```js
var common = common || {}
common.cookieManager = common.cookieManager || {};
common.cookieManager.getCookieValue = (name) => (
  document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + name + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)')?.pop() || ''
)

/**
 * set cookie with name value and life time
 * @param {string} name cookie name
 * @param {string} value cookie value
 * @param {number} expireTime s
 */
common.cookieManager.setCookie = async (name, value, expireTime = 0) => {
  const expires = (new Date(Date.now() + expireTime * 1000)).toUTCString();
  document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; expires=` + expires + ";path=/;"
}
```

You can modify the setCookie function by adding parameters yourself
according to [Document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

---

***But*** if you are using .NET MVC framework, it is better to set cookie in backend I thought
In your .NET WebApi Controller, should have a `Response` prop can use

Use the `Controller.Response` to set cookie with the ***CookieOptions class***

sample code:

```
Response.Cookies.Append("key", "value", new CookieOptions() { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), IsEssential = true });
```